# How to serve static generated pages via CDN with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use Next.js (9.5.2) for both Server Side Rendering and Static Site Generation. SSR works fine for me with assetPrefix. I am able to host all my static assets on CloudFront. However, I'm not sure what the best way is to host the static pages.

I am facing 2 issues.

1. `assetPrefix` is not applied to SSG pages. so the link to JS/CSS will be something like this `<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/styles.31b6de8d.chunk.css" as="style"/>`
2. Assume we host generated HTML on CDN and we are able to serve assets with `assetPrefix`, how do I use Next.js Incremental Static Regeneration with `fallback: true` in `getStaticPath`. My understanding is that page will generated on the server side if the corresponding HTML is not found.

Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: hi @Andrew, I am trying to cache my nextJS application on CDN for performance improvement. Can you please guide me where to start with?

Answer (score 9):

I have partial answers to my own question.

**For issue 1**:

The issue is my own fault. `assetPrefix` worked with SSR but not for SSG because I didn't pass in environmental variables properly. In my situation, we have 2 different CDN URLs for production and staging. So I have something like the following in `next.config.js`. Because `MY_ENV` is passed in from PM2, which starts my app, it is guaranteed that `MY_ENV` will always be available when Next.js needs to access `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
const isProd = process.env.MY_ENV === 'production';
const isStaging = process.env.MY_ENV === 'staging';
const isDevelopment = process.env.MY_ENV === 'development';

if (isProd) {
  assetPrefix = 'https://mycdn.cloudfront.net/';
} else if (isStaging) {
  assetPrefix = 'https://mycdn.cloudfront.net/staging';
}
```

However, when I run `next build` for static pages, the build step doesn't use PM2 thus `MY_ENV` is not available. To make it work, I need to run the build twice with different variables.

```
"build": "npm-run-all --parallel build:production build:staging",
"build:production": "MY_ENV=production next build",
"build:staging": "MY_ENV=staging next build",
```

**For issue 2**:

If I'm able to pre-generate all static pages. I can just put everything on CDN and they will work.

In my situation, ISR is a better fit. The way I get ISR to work is to ask the server to return the HTML for every request instead of hosting on the CDN. Since all other assets are hosted on the CDN, the performance is still pretty good and this solution works out well for my situation.

If you are like me who struggled a bit on this issue, I hope my answer helps you out.

Comment: thank you andrew-zheng for this answer. For issue 2: as I understand what you did you configured domain on ClooudFront CDN and mapped it to your original server and it works automatically with ISR? When you request a static page with ISR via CDN domain, then the server returns it, and because this page has Response Header Cache Control with max-age, it works automatically with CDN? or it is not cached with CDN since it does not have Cache Control public header?

Comment: @Juri, you are right. For ISR, the page is not cached with CDN but on the server.

Comment: Hey, i am also trying to figure out any solution for this. I understand that CDN will request your server for any new page but how will you return the newly generated page? If the page is longer it can take time to generate. Also, nextjs does not provide any hook that we know if any new page have been generated or old page have been updated

Comment: @Rahul I haven't touch this for awhile. but basically, your new page will be server-side rendered. I don't think you will know if a new copy of the page has been generated. Maybe schedule a job on your server to check time stamp? If you are using the ISR approach, you will have a expiration time.